Como não permitir dois exe delphi?
Estou com uma aplicação que não pode ser executada duas vezes, no entanto, quando é um sistema operacional server, que permite usuários simultâneos, eu consigo abrir o exe no usuário A e no usuário B, como posso bloquear essa função?

No passado já utilizei a biblioteca jcl para fazer esta verificação, se tiver disponibilidade de adicionar bibliotecas de terceiros, de uma olhada no método https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:TJclAppInstances.SessionInstanceCount

Olá. Eu uso um bloqueio para a execução do programa na mesma máquina. Não sei se é o seu caso.
Ex.
 if RedeDef = False then
    begin
      Instancia := createMutex(nil, false, 'Prestimo');
      if WaitForSingleObject(Instancia, 0) = wait_Timeout then
        begin
           Application.MessageBox('O programa já está aberto!',
                                              'Prestimo - Atenção',MB_ICONSTOP);
          Exit
        end;
    end;


Windows.CreatMutex declarado em Winapi.Windows.

Não sei se faz difenreça ser Windows Server mas eu faço assim:
var
  HprevHist: Thandle;

begin
  Application.Initialize;

  begin
    HprevHist := FindWindow(Nil, PChar('NOME e\ou TITULO DO APP'));
    if(HprevHist <> 0)then
    begin
      Application.MessageBox('Aplicativo já se encontra em execução!','Atenção',MB_OK);
      ShowWindow(HprevHist,SW_NORMAL);
      Application.Terminate;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

Application.Title := 'Servidor Central'; //mesmo nome que pode ser encontrado aqui

